# Using pgfkeys to switch between "enumerate" and "enumerate*" when using the enumitem package with the package option "inline""

Tags: lists, enumitem, pgfkeys

No matter what I seem to do, I'm just getting this wrong.

I would like to be able to set a key to determine how my list is arranged.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\pgfkeys{/ae/testing/.cd,
  list collection/.store in=\mylistcollection,
  arrange horizontally/.code={\def\myenumitem{enumerate*}},
}
\def\myenumitem{enumerate}
\def\aeset#1{\pgfkeys{/ae/testing/.cd,#1}}
\def\aeget#1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/ae/testing/#1}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mylist}{ m }
    {\bgroup
     \aeset{#1}
      \expandafter\begin\expandafter{\myenumitem}[label=(\alph*)]
        \foreach \x in \mylistcollection {\item \x}
      \expandafter\end\expandafter{\myenumitem}
      \egroup
    }

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\mylist{list collection={a,b,c,d}}

\mylist{list collection={a,b,c,d},arrange horizontally}

\end{document}
```

Initially, I wanted to have the key `arrange horizontally` be defined as

```
arrange horizontally/.is if=ArrangeHorizontally,
```

and then also define

```
\newif\ifArrangeHorizontally
\ArrangeHorizontallyfalse
```

but that too was giving me problems (in fact, I've never been able to get `.is if` to work the way I expect them to.

Nevertheless, the code as I've written it above results in an error:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\item ...ctor \relax \fi }\color@endgroup \egroup 
                                                  \enit@outeritem 
l.32 ...collection={a,b,c,d},arrange horizontally}

?
```

I don't see what's going on.  I would think everything should expand as expected.

I also tried working around using `\expandafter\begin\expandafter{....` by directly calling `\enit@enumerate*` or `enit@enumerate`.  But that too resulted in errors.

**UPDATE**

Here is my attempt with the `.is if` approach

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\pgfkeys{/ae/testing/.cd,
  list collection/.store in=\mylistcollection,
  arrange horizontally/.is if=ArrangeHorizontally,
}
\newif\ifArrangeHorizontally
\ArrangeHorizontallyfalse

\def\myenumitem{enumerate}
\def\aeset#1{\pgfkeys{/ae/testing/.cd,#1}}
\def\aeget#1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/ae/testing/#1}}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\mylist}{ m }
    {\bgroup
     \aeset{#1}
  \ifArrangeHorizontally\@nameuse{enumerate*}\else\expandafter\@nameuse{enumerate}\fi
    [label=(\alph*)]
    \foreach \x in \mylistcollection {\item \x}
  \ifArrangeHorizontally\@nameuse{endenumerate*}\else\expandafter\@nameuse{endenumerate}\fi

      \egroup
    }

\makeatother
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\mylist{list collection={a,b,c,d}}

\mylist{list collection={a,b,c,d},arrange horizontally=true}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would do it. The code uses `\etoolbox`'s list processing tools, especially `\forlistloop{<handler>}{<list macro>}` (which is expandable). And since it's already loaded it also uses `\etoolbox`'s boolean tests and its `\ifdefempty` and `\csuse`.

I added a warning message in case an empty list or no list has been given.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{pgfkeys,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newbool{ae@enumerate@inline}
\def\ae@list@collection{}

\pgfkeys{
  ae/.cd ,
    list collection/.code =
      \forcsvlist{\listadd\ae@list@collection}{#1} ,
    arrange horizontally/.is if = ae@enumerate@inline
}

\newrobustcmd\aeset[1]{\pgfkeys{ae/.cd,#1}}

\newrobustcmd\aelist[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \aeset{#1}%
    \ifdefempty\ae@list@collection{%
      \@latex@warning@no@line{%
        \string\aelist: Empty List! I'll do nothing\on@line
      }%
    }
    {%
      \ifbool{ae@enumerate@inline}
        {\csuse{enumerate*}}
        {\enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
      \forlistloop{\item}\ae@list@collection
      \ifbool{ae@enumerate@inline}
        {\csuse{endenumerate*}}
        {\endenumerate}%
    }%
    \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\aelist{list collection={one,two}}

\aelist{list collection={one,two},arrange horizontally}

\aelist{list collection={one,two}}

\aeset{arrange horizontally=true}

\aelist{list collection={one,two}}

\end{document}
```